# Configuration Spring.Http.Client.WebClientHttpRequestFactory

Tags: c#, dropbox, spring.net

I'm creating an application to post files on Dropbox service with spring-net-social-dropbox library.
Is it possible to change/configure properties of WebClientHttpRequestFactory class? I'd like to change Timeout property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast your `IDropbox` instance to `DropboxTemplate`.
Then you will get access to the underlying `RestTemplate` instance which have a `RequestFactory` property.